# SignalR not working properly after deploying on azure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr

I had gone through questions over here but not found solution . I am using the persistent connection SignalR to broadcast to particular clients for updating the page (some grids) . It works well on localhost and particular parts got updated .

When it got deployed over azure it works fine initially but if user is idle for some duration and log in again after few hours the page is not getting updated through signalR .
So if user waits even for long time no updates over the page .
It looks that its not broadcasting to particular client .

Is it related to servicebus issue(as mentioned in one article over internet) ?
or am i doing something wrong ? 
Need some suggestion or help .

Answer (score 0):

Are you using multiple roles? If you are you need to use scaleout. You can learn more about scaling out here http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/performance/scaleout-in-signalr

Comment: Then you don't have to worry about scaleout.

Comment: Link is broken. I think this here is the current one leading to the help topic "Introduction to Scaleout in SignalR": http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/performance/scaleout-in-signalr

Comment: @davidfowl: Please summarize the link as links can break at any time. A link to an answer is not an answer.

Comment: Links to documentation aren't supposed to break. TL;DR you need redis, sql or service bus to make multiple roles work with SignalR

Answer (score 0):

Specifically for Azure, there's a Nuget package and instructions that help you get set up scaling SignalR using the Azure Service Bus to keep things in sync.  Here's a link to the detailed instructions specifically for Azure, though @dfowler's link works, too, if you want to scale it out using another method.

http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/performance-and-scaling/scaleout-with-windows-azure-service-bus

Comment: Please provide the "detailed instructions" in the answer and not simply link to an article. Links can become broken, and in this specific case the link is already broken.